# ¿Como establecer seleccion de un elemento <select> HTML con Java Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy insertando elementos en base de datos usando AJAX al mismo tiempo estoy refrescando una lista  para que muestre los elementos agregados...Nesecito que cada vez que haga esto la lista quede seleccionada en el ultimo elemento q a su vez ocupa la ultima posicion...

Como puedo hacer esto ??

Escribi este codigo pero no me esta funcionando...

```
function JsFuncion (paso,tipoDocumento,idDocumento,indice)
{
      $.ajax({
               url: "/WorkFlow/CreateFlujoDocumento",
               data: { paso: paso, tipoDocumento: tipoDocumento, idDocumento: idDocumento},
               dataType: 'json',
               type: 'POST',
               cache: false,
               success: function (data) 
                          {
                            FlujosAprobacion(indice); //AQUI REFRESCO MI LISTA flujos.
                            var f = document.getElementById('flujos').length;
                            $("#flujos").val(f - 1);
                          }
             });
  }
```

Con este codigo refresco mi lista :

```
  function FlujosAprobacion(indice) {

      var arrayFlujos = [];
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/WorkFlow/GetFlujos",
          data: { id: indice },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              data.length > 0 ? $('#triggerModal').removeAttr('disabled') : $('#triggerModal').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              $("#flujos").empty();
              $('#flujos').append('<option selected disabled value="-1">Seleccione...</option>');
              $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                  arrayFlujos.push(value);
                  $('#flujos').append('<option  value="' + value.id + '">' + value.descripcion + '</option>');
              });
          }
      });
}



 $("#flujos").select2({
        multiple: false,
        placeholder: 'Seleccione...'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola prueba con esto,

```
function JsFuncion (paso,tipoDocumento,idDocumento,indice)
{
      $.ajax({
               url: "/WorkFlow/CreateFlujoDocumento",
               data: { paso: paso, tipoDocumento: tipoDocumento, idDocumento: idDocumento},
               dataType: 'json',
               type: 'POST',
               cache: false,
               success: function (data) 
                          {
                            FlujosAprobacion(indice); //AQUI REFRESCO MI LISTA flujos.
                            var f = document.getElementById('flujos');
                            f.children[f.children.length-1].setAttribute('selected','');
                          }
             });
  }
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos